# Constructing model category from given category

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Given a model category $\mathcal{M}$, Goerss and Hopkins constructed a subcategory (see *Structured Ring Spectra*, p. 160) $\mathbf{E}$ of $\mathcal{M}$ such that:

- If $X\in\mathbf{E}$ and $Y$ is weakly equivalent to $X$, then $Y\in\mathbf{E}$.
- A morphism $f$ in $\mathcal{M}$ is in $\mathbf{E}$ if and only if it is a weak equivalence.

If $\mathbf{E}$ is the category whose objects are $\mathcal{M}$ and morphisms are the weak equivalences, then $\mathbf{E}$ is written $\mathbf{E}(\mathcal{M})$. My question is as follows: is it possible to recover the model category $\mathcal{M}$ from $\mathbf{E}(\mathcal{M})$? Is there any nontrivial model structure on $\mathcal{M}$ that is useful/interesting?

Comment: What do you mean by your last sentence? M comes with a model structure... In general I think not, since you can consider a model structure on a complete/cocomplete category where isomorphisms are the weak equivalences, and so E is just the core (assuming we take all the objects of M). There's no way to recover a category from its core.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Sorry if that seemed ambiguous. What I meant was, given $\mathbf{E}(\mathcal{M})$, what kind of maps in the (not yet model) category $\mathcal{M}$ can we choose to be cofibrations and fibrations such that they endow $\mathcal{M}$ with the structure of a model category?

Comment: Stated otherwise, can we choose cofibrations and fibrations in a category $(\mathcal{M},\mathbf{E}(\mathcal{M}))$ with weak equivalences such that $\mathcal{M}$ becomes a model category with these weak equivalences and chosen cofibrations and fibrations?

Comment: Part of the point of model categories is to endow a category with weak equivalences with enough structure to make localization by those weak equivalences manageable. So there's something nontrivial going on, and it is not hard to write down categories with weak equivalences with horrible localizations (which therefore don't extend to model categories).

Comment: Supposing that you remember at least the underlying category $\mathcal M$, which is a must, the answer is even no, since there are well known different model structures in the same category with the same weak equivalences (e.g. chain complexes + quasi-isomorphisms). (Co)fibrations are just a way of constructing resolutions in order to compute derived functors, and we know that this can be done in several different ways, in general.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Fernando's comment already provides an answer.

Comment: @David I've also voted to close my question because I've understood how stupid the question is.

Comment: I wouldn't say the question is stupid, just not for this forum since the answer is well documented in standard books on model categories (e.g. Hovey's). It would be a very good question for the math stack exchange, and explaining explicit examples would be pertinent there.

Comment: There is also this paper which shows how non-uniquely you can choose a model structure. http://faculty.uml.edu/tbeke/cofib.pdf

Comment: @Bogdan The title seems to be almost exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar It's only in some cases, presheaves if I recall, but at least this shows that in this case there is a big freedom of choices! I believe it usually is the case. However sometimes you don't have that many choices. The craziest example that I know of is the UNIQUE model structure on small cat with weak eq usual equivalences, see here http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/canonical+model+structure+on+Cat#uniqueness_of_model_structure

Comment: A nitpick: Goerss and Hopkins don't _construct_ any particular such subcategory (at least on the page cited) -- they simply consider the situation where you have the information given. Actually, this is a more interesting question if we specify which $E$ we're working with: if $E$ consists of all objects of $M$ then certainly we can't recover the cofibrations and fibrations. But what if $E$ consists of just the bifibrant objects? Can we recover the fibrations and cofibrations given just the data of the category $M$ and the subcategory of bifibrant objects and weak equivalences? I don't know.

Comment: @tcamps Right, that is more interesting. I've thought about it some time ago, but nothing much came out of it.

Answer (score 2):

**A long comment:**
When you have a model category $\mathcal{M}$ in particular you have an enriched $Ho(sSet)$-module structure on $Ho(\mathcal{M})$ (in the sense of Hovey) i.e. the homotopy category $Ho(\mathcal{M})$ is tensored and cotensored over $Ho(sSet)$ in a compatible way. Let me use the following analogy: suppose that $R$ is a ring and $M$ is an abelian group and imagine you have an action of some elements of $R$ on some elements of $M$ and you are asking the question wether this action is a restriction of honest $R$-module structure on $M$. So your question (if I understand it) should be formulated as follows:

Suppose that we have a (co)complete category $\mathcal{M}$ and a subcategory $ \mathbf{E}(\mathcal{M})$ such that the category  $\mathcal{M}[\mathbf{E}(\mathcal{M})^{-1}] $ exists , does it come from a model structure on $\mathcal{M}$ such that $Ho(\mathcal{M})\simeq \mathcal{M}[\mathbf{E}(\mathcal{M})^{-1}]$?

**Resume:**

1) In order to have a model structure on $\mathcal{M}$ whit a subcategory $ \mathbf{E}(\mathcal{M})$ of weak equivalences such that $\mathcal{M}[\mathbf{E}(\mathcal{M})^{-1}] $ exists a necessary condition is to have an 
enriched $Ho(sSet)$-module structure on $\mathcal{M}[\mathbf{E}(\mathcal{M})^{-1}]$.

2) The Homotopy category $Ho(\mathcal{M})$ depends on the class of weak equivalences but the additional structure of enriched $Ho(sSet)$-module structure on $Ho(\mathcal{M})$ is given by the class of cofibrations (fibrations).